# Faster way of Appending/combining thousands (42000) of netCDF files in NCO

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nco, cdo-climate

I seem to be having trouble properly combining thousands of netCDF files (42000+) (3gb in size, for this particular folder/variable). The main variable that i want to combine has a structure of (6, 127, 118) i.e (time,lat,lon)
Im appending each file 1 by 1 since the number of files is too long.

I have tried:

```
for i in input_source/**/**/*.nc; do ncrcat -A -h append_output.nc $i append_output.nc ; done
```

but this method seems to be really slow (order of kb/s and seems to be getting slower as more files are appended) and is also giving a warning:

```
ncrcat: WARNING Intra-file non-monotonicity. Record coordinate "forecast_period" does not monotonically increase between (input file file1.nc record indices: 17, 18) (output file file1.nc record indices 17, 18) record coordinate values 6.000000, 1.000000
```

that basically just increases the variable "forecast_period" 1-6 n-times. n = 42000files. i.e. [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6......n]
And despite this warning i can still open the file and ncrcat does what its supposed to, it is just slow, at-least for this particular method

I have also tried adding in the option:

```
--no_tmp_fl
```

but this gives an eror:

```
ERROR: nco__open() unable to open file "append_output.nc"
```

full error attached below

If it helps, im using wsl and ubuntu in windows 10.
Im new to bash and any comments would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these commands should work:

```
ncrcat --no_tmp_fl -h *.nc
```

or

```
ls input_source/**/**/*.nc | ncrcat --no_tmp_fl -h append_output.nc
```

Your original command is slow because you open and close the output files N times. These commands open it once, fill-it up, then close it.

Comment: The first command is one of the first things i tried, however, it results in an  ' argument list too long', and similar to the 2nd command.

Comment: However, i just had a thought that rather than passing all files at once i separate them by years and use a for loop to go through each year. And then finally concat the combined years into one. Seems to work for now. Ill accept ur answer as its the closest one and provides why the initial command is slow, cheers

Comment: I'm not sure how pipes work on Windows and WSL but both those commands would likely work fine in UNIX. Glad you found a workaround. The other thing you can do in the future is name the files as described in the manual to fit the ncrcat -n algorithm that automatically generates names, then the command line is extremely short.

Answer (score 1):

I would use CDO for this task. Given the huge number of files it is recommended to first sort them on time (assuming you want to merge them along the time axis). After that, you can use

```
cdo cat *.nc outfile
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried CDO before, but it creates output files that are 10x than the input files. I.e. input file of 50mb gives an output file of 500mb when concatenating. For NCO this is not the case, actually it even reduces it.

Comment: In that case you could investigate why it inflates the output so much. This is strange behavior, maybe you need to pass some more flags to CDO to specify data types and/or filetype. Not sure if I can further help you there. Good luck!